# Issues upgrading from MongoDB version 3.6 to 4.0 on Debian 10 - Buster

Tags: debian, mongodb

Im running mongo 3.6.23 on Debian 10 and I'd like to upgrade it to 7.0. From what I've read online, mongo needs to be updated in release order to avoid errors. However, it seems like there is [no support for mongo <4.2 on Debian 10](https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/dists/buster/mongodb-org/).

Upgrading to 4.2 directly fails, and produces the following error in mongo's log:

```
Collection does not have UUID in KVCatalog
```

The consensus solution for this online is to upgrade from 3.6 > 4.0 > 4.2.

However, attempting to upgrade to 4.0 using [Jessie](https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/dists/jessie/mongodb-org/) or Stretch versions of mongo leads to the following error when attempting to install:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mongodb-org-server:
mongodb-org-server depends on libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2); however:
Package libcurl3 is not installed.
```

And it appears that libcurl3 cant be installed on Debian 10. Are there any other solutions that I can try?

**Edit 2/2/24:**

4.0.9 may be installable using these, Im pretty sure these worked but I didnt have time to do whatever the next step is after (running some variation of mongod --repair):

Install ubuntu debs:

```
wget https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/mongodb-org/4.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/mongodb-org-mongos_4.0.9_amd64.deb
wget https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/mongodb-org/4.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/mongodb-org-server_4.0.9_amd64.deb
wget https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/mongodb-org/4.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/mongodb-org_4.0.9_amd64.deb
wget https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/mongodb-org/4.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/mongodb-org-shell_4.0.9_amd64.deb
wget https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/mongodb-org/4.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/mongodb-org-tools_4.0.9_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-org-mongos_4.0.9_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-org-server_4.0.9_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-org_4.0.9_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-org-shell_4.0.9_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-org-tools_4.0.9_amd64.deb
```

After that, pretty sure youre supposed to run this and pray that it finishes with no errors:

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /mongodb/data --directoryperdb --repair
```

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to this? Same problem here.

Comment: I was never able to get it to work, I think I was on the right track but I ran out of time. I added some info to the post on what I tried that worked.

Comment: thanks man. I did those without success also. Probably will downgrade to 9 and do it from there.